# I had unopened block cheese in my fridge for 8 months is it still good?

Tags: cheese

I had unopened block cheese in fridge for 8 months is it still good?

Comment: What kind of cheese? Parmesan and gouda probably  make a difference.

Comment: If there an expiration date on it?

Answer (score 5):

Mold is usually the first sign of degradation.
I just cut that stuff off.
Listeria *tends* to hit softer cheeses, but there's always a danger.
If it's not moldy, not Brie or similar, I'd eat it. I've eaten 2 year old fridge cheese before, and not died. But as with all matters involving health, you're on your own, and the question is really outside the purview of this stack.

Answer (score 0):

The problem,  generally speaking, is that your fridge  is not a very good cheese  cave. Yes, usually a homemade cave is  made from a wine fridge but there is slightly more to it.  You need to make your cave humid enough so that the  bacteria you introduce to your cheese thrives. You would also need to have your cave in a dark place.

There is also a very real chance that the other foods in the fridge could lead cross-contamination, god only knows what micro organisms a  piece of uncooked chicken could bring to aging cheese. Odours could also lead to unsavoury flavours.

A proper cheese cave is a controlled environment and without this control you really are just playing culinary russian-roulette.